# Highcharts WorldMap drillup function changing the orientation of the map

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a highcharts world map with drilldown functionality. Drilldown works perfectly but when I drillup, the map changes orientation.

Please advice.

This is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0fq68y2u/1/

```
    const drilldown = async function (e) {
        if (!e.seriesOptions) {
            const chart = this,
                mapKey = `countries/${e.point.drilldown}/${e.point.drilldown}-all`;

            // Handle error, the timeout is cleared on success
            let fail = setTimeout(() => {
                if (!Highcharts.maps[mapKey]) {
                    chart.showLoading(`
                        <i class="icon-frown"></i>
                        Failed loading ${e.point.name}
                    `);
                    fail = setTimeout(() => {
                        chart.hideLoading();
                    }, 1000);
                }
            }, 3000);

            // Show the Font Awesome spinner
            chart.showLoading('<i class="icon-spinner icon-spin icon-3x"></i>');

            // Load the drilldown map
            const topology = await fetch(
                `https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/${mapKey}.topo.json`
            ).then(response => response.json());

            const data = Highcharts.geojson(topology);

            // Set a non-random bogus value
            data.forEach((d, i) => {
                d.value = i;
            });

            // Apply the recommended map view if any
            chart.mapView.update(
                Highcharts.merge(
                    {
                        insets: undefined,
                        padding: 0
                    },
                    topology.objects.default['hc-recommended-mapview']
                )
            );

            // Hide loading and add series
            chart.hideLoading();
            clearTimeout(fail);
            chart.addSeriesAsDrilldown(e.point, {
                name: e.point.name,
                data,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    format: '{point.name}'
                }
            });
        }
    };

    // On drill up, reset to the top-level map view
    const afterDrillUp = function (e) {
        if (e.seriesOptions.custom && e.seriesOptions.custom.mapView) {
            e.target.mapView.update(
                Highcharts.merge(
                    { insets: undefined },
                    e.seriesOptions.custom.mapView
                ),
                false
            );
        }
    };

    (async () => {

        const topology = await fetch(
            'https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/custom/world-highres3.topo.json'
        ).then(response => response.json());

        const data = Highcharts.geojson(topology);
        
        console.log('data', data)

        const mapView = topology.objects.default['hc-recommended-mapview'];
        
        console.log('mapView', mapView)

        // Set drilldown pointers
        data.forEach((d, i) => {
            d.drilldown = d.properties['hc-key'];
            d.value = i; // Non-random bogus data
        });

        // Instantiate the map
        Highcharts.mapChart('container', {
            chart: {
                events: {
                    drilldown,
                    afterDrillUp
                },
                backgroundColor: '#B6DCF4'
            },

            title: {
                text: 'Highcharts Map Drilldown'
            },
            legend: {
            enabled: false
            },

            mapView,

            mapNavigation: {
                enabled: true,
                buttonOptions: {
                    verticalAlign: 'bottom'
                }
            },

            plotOptions: {
                map: {
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            color: '#EEDD66'
                        }
                    }
                }
            },

            series: [{
                data,
                nullColor: 'white',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    format: '{point.properties.postal-code}'
                },
                custom: {
                    mapView
                }
            }],

            drilldown: {
                activeDataLabelStyle: {
                    color: '#FFFFFF',
                    textDecoration: 'none',
                    textOutline: '1px #000000'
                },
                breadcrumbs: {
                    floating: true,
                    relativeTo: 'spacingBox'
                },
                drillUpButton: {
                    relativeTo: 'spacingBox',
                    position: {
                        x: 0,
                        y: 60
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    })();
```

Answer (score 0):

As you consoled log, the default `mapView` is currently `undefined`. To fix that, you need to set the `mapView`, e.g.:

```
const mapView = {
    projection: {
      name: 'Miller',
      rotation: 0
    }
  };
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/wx3c0k49/

Comment: Thanks @magdalena. Why does the map zoom out when I click the Main link at the top? Any way to reset it to the old zoom level?

Comment: HI, added some amendments like zoom and center: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8p07smqt/